# Get Value from Jquery slider and make it ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i`m trying to get the value from the slider and put it as ID . 
here my code :

jQuery :

```
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
                var SliderValueNumber = $('#slider-range-max').slider('value');
                $('div.ForView').attr('id', SliderValueNumber );
            });
```

it`s working nice , but when i click on the button only . i need when the slider value changing the ID change too !!

Comment: you get value from button and set it again to slider as its value?

Comment: i`m trying to get the value from the slider and put it as ID . when the value change the ID change Too

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `change` event of the slider.

```
$('#slider-range-max').on('slidechange', function() {
    // Do what you want
});
```

Look at the jQuery UI API documentation for more : http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into change event. See [this fiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/5j46cd8d/)

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log(ui.value);
  }
});
```